# How to handle client requests within server in C with socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I want to handle multiple client requests.

Should I call `listen()` just once and call `accept()` for every new client request?

Comment: But if you want to handle them at the same time then there is more to it.

Comment: Should I use select function?

Comment: I wrote a code by using select() and now I can manage multiple requests. Reference link: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out D.J. Bernstein's tcpserver (see http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html). Basically, you can simply run your C program under tcpserver, and tcpserver will handle everything as far as setting up the sockets, listing for incoming connections on whatever port you are using, etc. When an incoming connection arrives on the port that you specify, tcpserver will spawn an instance of your program and pipe incoming info from the client to your program's STDIN, and pipe outgoing info from your program's STDOUT back to the client. This way, you can concentrate on your program's core logic (and simply read/write to stdout/stdin), and let tcpserver handle all of the heavy lifting as far as the sockets, etc.